# How to repeat same array in an another array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a set e.g.,

```
set={[1],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1]}
```

However, I need to repeat `[1,2,3,..]` several times. Lets say I have `[1:r]` and need repeat the same for `n` times. Then, it should be in the following form:

```
set={[1],[1,2,..r], ... ,[1,2,..r],[1]}
```

I tried to use

```
repmat([1:3],1,3)
%   1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
```

which has repeated elements but in the same array. I need it as 3D format.

Comment: post your code http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `repmat([1:3], 1, 3)` which will repeat `1:3` 3 times *within the same numeric array*, you want to pass the cell array element as the first input to `repmat` (note the `{}` surrounding the array).

```
repmat({1:3}, 1, 3)

%   { [1 2 3], [1 2 3], [1 2 3] }
```

To create your array from an initial cell array, you could do something like this

```
r = 3; n = 3;

initial = {1, 1:r, 1};
final = [initial(1), repmat(initial(2), 1, n), initial(3)];

%   { [1], [1 2 3], [1 2 3], [1 2 3], [1] }
```